# Rails clockwork display on log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clockwork

I'm trying to learn how to use the gem `clockwork`. I'm just trying to test on my Mac and putting a line onto the development log.  I have it set at 3 minutes just for testing.

I have the following in lib/clock.rb :

```
require 'clockwork'
module Clockwork
  handler do |job|
    puts "Running #{job} =================================="
  end
Clockwork.every(3.minutes, 'dailyjob')
end
```

Then I have lib/tasks/dailyjob.rb

```
class DailyJob
  def perform
    Rails.logger.info "Daily Job ========================================="
  end
end
```

I then start Clockworks via the console `$ clockwork clock.rb`. It starts up and every 3 minutes the console says:

```
Running dailyjob ==================================
I, [2014-03-04T11:03:32.084240 #66442]  INFO -- : Triggering 'dailyjob'
```

But, nothing shows up in the development.log file.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try adding `require './config/boot'` and `require './config/environment'` below your first require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [docs](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork), Clockwork will only write to STDOUT unless you configure it otherwise:

> By default Clockwork logs to STDOUT. In case you prefer your own
>   logger implementation you have to specify the logger configuration
>   option. See example below.

Example from the docs is this:

```
module Clockwork
  configure do |config|
    config[:sleep_timeout] = 5
    config[:logger] = Logger.new(log_file_path)
    config[:tz] = 'EST'
    config[:max_threads] = 15
    config[:thread] = true
  end
end
```